# repo sync results in "fatal: Not a git repository: 'working_dir/.repo/projects/external/ipsec-tools.git'"

Tags: android, git, android-source

I am trying to download the Android source code and am following the procedure described in https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html, which consists of installing the repo script and then running

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
$ repo sync
```

to get the main branch. I have also tried using the `-f -j1` flags to go through errors and use only one core, as was suggested somewhere online. At this point, I think I am very close to getting the entire thing downloaded but it will invariably stop towards the end when working on ipsec-tools. It always gives the following output:

```
    Fetching project platform/external/ipsec-tools
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100     1  100     1    0     0      3      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     3
100 1690k  100 1690k    0     0  2307k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 2307k
fatal: Not a git repository: '/home/sebastian/WORKING_DIR/.repo/projects/external/ipsec-tools.git'
fatal: Not a git repository: '/home/sebastian/WORKING_DIR/.repo/projects/external/ipsec-tools.git'
fatal: Not a git repository: '/home/sebastian/WORKING_DIR/.repo/projects/external/ipsec-tools.git'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sebastian/WORKING_DIR/.repo/repo/main.py", line 500, in <module>
    _Main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/sebastian/WORKING_DIR/.repo/repo/main.py", line 476, in _Main
    result = repo._Run(argv) or 0
  File "/home/sebastian/WORKING_DIR/.repo/repo/main.py", line 155, in _Run
    result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
  File "/home/sebastian/WORKING_DIR/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 635, in Execute
    fetched = self._Fetch(to_fetch, opt)
  File "/home/sebastian/WORKING_DIR/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 339, in _Fetch
    self._FetchProjectList(**kwargs)
  File "/home/sebastian/WORKING_DIR/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 234, in _FetchProjectList
    success = self._FetchHelper(opt, project, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sebastian/WORKING_DIR/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 275, in _FetchHelper
    no_tags=opt.no_tags, archive=self.manifest.IsArchive)
  File "/home/sebastian/WORKING_DIR/.repo/repo/project.py", line 1110, in Sync_NetworkHalf
    no_tags=no_tags)):
  File "/home/sebastian/WORKING_DIR/.repo/repo/project.py", line 1845, in _RemoteFetch
    self.bare_git.pack_refs('--all', '--prune')
  File "/home/sebastian/WORKING_DIR/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2483, in runner
    p.stderr))
error.GitError: platform/external/ipsec-tools pack-refs: fatal: Not a git repository: '/home/sebastian/WORKING_DIR/.repo/projects/external/ipsec-tools.git'
```

Since it says it is not a git repository, I just went on a hunch and ran `git init` on the directory it indicated, which didn't work. I also tried deleting the entire ipsec-tools.git directory and running repo sync again so that it would start from scratch but it always gives the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check your filesystem and see if you are out of disk space.  Repo essentially checks out the git repository under `.repo/projects` then in your working directory creates the appropriate path to the contents of the git repository and the `.git` directory contents for that project point back via symlink to the git configuration files under the `.repo/projects` directory.  This looks as though it wasn't able to pull down everything correctly, which could be due to a disk space issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Larry. I wouldn't be surprised at all if it were a space issue, I am running a VM for this and actually had to increase its disk space and then expand its root partition, which was a big hassle. However, when I log in, it says I am only using about 40% of the total 60GB, which means I should have enough space to complete the download. Plus, before expanding I got explicit messages saying there was not enough space in the disk and now I am just getting these git errors. Do you still think that might be the reason?

Comment: Hmmm...it's possible if you had done the `repo init` followed by a `repo sync` and it failed due to disk space, then tried to re-run `repo sync` after expanding the disk.  It could have left the git repos in a weird state.  You may want to try blowing away your working directory and starting again.  Or, you could just try re-running `repo init` and `repo sync`, but I've had very mixed results with that approach in the past.

Comment: You were right. Starting from scratch again did the trick this time. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `repo forall -vc "git init" && repo sync`
worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

Its not necessary to start `sync` from scratch. Android is a huge repository to download from scratch and in interest of saving time and internet one can remove specific git repository (generally I have seen only 1 git directory being corrupt) and re-run the sync.

`repo` stores projects in

```
.repo/projects
```

but these are only soft links to actual git data, which is stored in

```
.repo/project-objects
```

follow the links in 'projects' and remove both the repositories and run sync again.
It worked for me.

Sample for **platform/frameworks/support**:

```
rm -fr .repo/projects/frameworks/support.git/ .repo/project-objects/platform/frameworks/support.git/
```

Sync only this project:

```
repo sync -j4 platform/frameworks/support
```

[I wanted to add this as comment, but its not allowing me - so added as answer]

Answer (score 0):

##### *Shorter answer:* Remove the offending repositories/data:

```
rm -Rf platform/external/ipsec-tools # from current path
rm -Rf .repo/projects/platform/external/ipsec-tools.git  # soft links 
rm -Rf .repo/project-objects/platform/external/ipsec-tools.git # actual git data
```

Better sync only the offending one:

```
repo sync platform/external/ipsec-tools
```

That worked for me for lineageos.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, where the repo command would exit with the same error.

I made a temporary folder, did a

```
repo init
```

then did

```
repo sync -j4 [PROJECT NAME]
```

where PROJECT NAME was the git which was getting corrupted. I then copied the .git directory from .repo/projects folder to the main directories' .repo/projects and again ran repo sync to finish it.